# How can I correctly return produced sequences in an F# recursive algorithm

Tags: functional-programming, f#, path-finding, chess, knights-tour

As a tutoring exercise I implemented the Knights Tour algorithm in CS and worked fine, after trying to port it to F# I cannot go past the part where I aggregate the resulting sequences of the Knight's path to return to the caller.

The code is this:

```
let offsets = [|(-2,-1);(-2,1);(-1,-2);(-1,2);(1,-2);(1,2);(2,-1);(2,1)|];

let squareToPair sqr = 
    (sqr % 8, sqr / 8)

let pairToSquare (col, row) = 
    row * 8 + col

// Memoizing function taken from Don Syme (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx)
let memoize f =
    let cache = ref Map.empty
    fun x ->
        match (!cache).TryFind(x) with
        | Some res -> res
        | None ->
             let res = f x
             cache := (!cache).Add(x,res)
             res

let getNextMoves square = 
    let (col, row) = squareToPair square
    offsets 
    |> Seq.map    (fun (colOff, rowOff) -> (col + colOff, row + rowOff))
    |> Seq.filter (fun (c, r) -> c >= 0 && c < 8 && r >= 0 && r < 8) // make sure we don't include squares out of the board
    |> Seq.map    (fun (c, r) -> pairToSquare (c, r))

let getNextMovesMemoized = memoize getNextMoves

let squareToBoard square = 
    1L <<< square

let squareToBoardMemoized = memoize squareToBoard

let getValidMoves square board =
    getNextMovesMemoized square 
    |> Seq.filter (fun sqr -> ((squareToBoardMemoized sqr) &&& board) = 0L)

// gets all valid moves from a particular square and board state sorted by moves which have less next possible moves
let getValidMovesSorted square board =
    getValidMoves square board
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun sqr -> (getValidMoves sqr board) |> Seq.length ) 

let nextMoves = getValidMovesSorted
let sqrToBoard = squareToBoardMemoized

let findPath square = 
    let board = sqrToBoard square
    let rec findPathRec brd sqr sequence = seq {
        match brd with 
            | -1L -> yield sequence
            |   _ -> for m in nextMoves sqr do yield! findPathRec (brd ||| (sqrToBoard m)) m m::sequence
    }

    findPathRec board square [square]

let solution = findPath ((4,4) |> pairToSquare) |> Seq.take 1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The type '(int64 -> seq<int>)' is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax, i.e. is not compatible with either seq<_>, IEnumerable<_> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method (using external F# compiler)
```

I could probably be misunderstanding how this work, but I would expect the results of nextMoves to be seq<_>. Is there a better way of doing this? Am I missing something? Any recommended patterns?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that `nextMoves` has type

```
val nextMoves : (int -> int64 -> seq<int>)
```

because it is identical to `getValidMovesSorted`.  You need to supply the `board` argument

Answer (score 1):

`nextMoves` is just `getValidMovesSorted` which takes two arguments (`square` and `board`) - now in  `findPath` you only provided one and I guess you wanted to write this

```
nextMoves sqr board
```

but then there are more issues in the rest of the code and it's really hard to figure out what you are trying to do

I think you wanted to do something like this:

```
let findPath square = 
    let board = sqrToBoard square
    let rec findPathRec brd sqr (sequence : int list) = 
        match brd with 
            | -1L -> sequence
            |   _ -> 
                [
                    for m in nextMoves sqr board do 
                    yield! findPathRec (brd ||| (sqrToBoard m)) m (m::sequence)
                ]
```

this will compile (but will result in an stack-overflow exception)

Comment: Hi Carsten, thanks for the answer, how did I miss that?? So basically I am trying to generate sequences where the knight visits the whole board once (this happens when brd = -1L) so I return. Otherwise I have to call the recursive function for possible moves.